# Как отправить картинку файлом python pyTelegramAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Нужно что бы бот отправлял картинку файлом, т.к телеграм сильно ужимает качество
сейчас бот отправляет картинку так:

```
  chislo = random.randint(1, len(imgUrls))
  p = (imgUrls[chislo])
  bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, p)
```

Бот берет URL картинки и отправляет её не сохраняя. Так вот как сделать, чтобы бот отправлял картинку файлом.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылаясь на эту информацию: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_document,

Вам просто необходимо поменять Ваш метод `send_photo` на `send_document` (аргументы те же)

Правда, согласно https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

```
In sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only work for gif, pdf and zip files.
```

Так что будет работать только для данных расширений